# Using a global struct with pthreads in C

Tags: c, multithreading, struct, pthreads, simulation

I'm trying to simulate clients going into a bank and being served by tellers over a period of time.  I am using a thread to determine if a client came into the bank via an arrival rate and am using multiple threads to represent tellers with an s service rate.  I am using a struct to hold the period of time, arrival rate, service rate, number of tellers, and the customer waiting queue.  I am attempting to share that struct between all threads but get "dereferencing pointer" errors and "request for member x in something not a structure" error.

```
//Used to store information input by user and the customer queue
struct shiftInfo {
    int tellers;
    int serviceTime;
    int simTime;
    int sampleInterval;
    int threadID;
    float arrivalRate;
    int Q[]; //Customer Queue
};
```

The information is passed from into the struct from the command line via

```
    struct shiftInfo *Q = malloc(sizeof(struct shiftInfo) + (maxCust*sizeof(int)));
    struct shiftInfo info;
    info.simTime = atoi(argv[1]);
    info.arrivalRate = atof(argv[2]);
    info.tellers = atoi(argv[3]);
    info.serviceTime = atoi(argv[4]);
    info.sampleInterval = atoi(argv[5]);
    //Initiates Q to 0
    for (int i = 0; i < maxCust; i++)
        info.Q[i] = 0;
```

The teller, timer, and customer threads are created and terminated by a main thread

```
  //Manager thread is main thread
  pthread_t manager;
  iret = pthread_create(&manager, NULL, mainThread, (void *)&info);
  if (iret){
    printf("ERROR: return code %d\n", iret);
    exit(-1);
    }
```

To keep this short I'm going to only ask about the timer thread and hopefully apply the answer to the other threads.  The timer thread is created in the main thread by:

```
  int status;
  struct shiftInfo *I = info; 
  pthread_t time;
      status = pthread_create(&time, NULL, timer, (void *)info);
      if (status){
        printf("ERROR CODE: %d\n", status);
        exit(-1);
    }
```

And the timer thread function is:

```
void *timer(void *info){
    int timeRemaining = info -> simTime;
    while(timeRemaining){
        sleep(1);
        timeRemaining--;
        }
}
```

For "int timeRemaining = info -> simTime;" I get the warning "dereferencing void pointer" and the error  request for member âsimTimeâ in something not a structure or union.
Any advice would be appreciate.

Also, I create the customer thread identically to the way I create the timer thread but receive a warning (warning: passing argument 3 of âpthread_createâ makes pointer from integer without a cast [enabled by default]) that I do not receive when creating any other thread, what causes that?

```
pthread_t customer;
    status = pthread_create(&customer, NULL, customer, (void *)info);
        if (status){
            printf("ERROR CODE: %d\n", status);
            exit(-1);
        }
```

Comment: Please don't mutate the question so that answers are invalidated!

Comment: Sorry, was trying to update it with answers to avoid repeated ones, I'll change it back.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's quite a few mistakes and typos you made.  The first mistake is here:

```
struct shiftInfo *Q = malloc(sizeof(struct shiftInfo) + (maxCust*sizeof(int)));
struct shiftInfo info;
info.simTime = atoi(argv[1]);
info.arrivalRate = atof(argv[2]);
info.tellers = atoi(argv[3]);
info.serviceTime = atoi(argv[4]);
info.sampleInterval = atoi(argv[5]);
//Initiates Q to 0
for (int i = 0; i < maxCust; i++)
    info.Q[i] = 0;
```

You allocate the right amount of space in `Q` but you don't ever use that anywhere.  Instead, you use `info`, which does not have any space for `info.Q` allocated.  Therefore, `info.Q[i] = 0` writes past the bounds of `info`.  Suggested fix:

```
struct shiftInfo *info = malloc(sizeof(struct shiftInfo) + (maxCust*sizeof(int)));
info->simTime = atoi(argv[1]);
info->arrivalRate = atof(argv[2]);
info->tellers = atoi(argv[3]);
info->serviceTime = atoi(argv[4]);
info->sampleInterval = atoi(argv[5]);
//Initiates Q to 0
for (int i = 0; i < maxCust; i++)
    info->Q[i] = 0;
```

Next mistake was this:

```
status = pthread_create(&time, NULL, timer, (void *)info);
```

In your code, `info` was a struct.  But you are trying to cast it to a pointer.  If you use my suggested fix above, `info` will be a pointer and you can leave this code as is.  You will need to make sure all your calls to `pthread_create` pass `(void *)info` and not `(void *)&info`.

The last mistake is here:

```
void *timer(void *info){
    int timeRemaining = info -> simTime;
```

Try this instead:

```
void *timer(void *arg){
    struct shiftInfo *info = (struct shiftInfo *) arg;
    int timeRemaining = info -> simTime;
```

Comment: Thank you, I made your first two change recommendations, as seen now in the post, but the change to void *timer seems to make simTime into a local variable, I want the changes to simTime that timer makes to be readable from all threads.

Comment: Don't use `timeRemaining` at all.  Just use `info->simTime`.  Any changes to `info->simTime` should be visible to all threads because you passed the same `info` to each thread in `pthread_create`.

Comment: Are you suggesting something like ` void *timer(void *arg){
 struct shiftInfo *info = (struct shiftInfo *) arg;
 while(info -> simTime){
  sleep(1);
  (info -> simTime)--;
  }
}
` That seems to get rid of the errors in that section, but I still have the other errors mentioned in the original post. @JS1

Comment: I'm just learning multithreading and have several dynamically allocated arrays that need passed to each pthread.  This answer really helped me simplify my code and keeps me from having to duplicate unnecessary data.

Answer (score 0):

This fragment is problematic:

```
struct shiftInfo *Q = malloc(sizeof(struct shiftInfo) + (maxCust*sizeof(int)));
struct shiftInfo info;
info.simTime = atoi(argv[1]);
info.arrivalRate = atof(argv[2]);
info.tellers = atoi(argv[3]);
info.serviceTime = atoi(argv[4]);
info.sampleInterval = atoi(argv[5]);
//Initiates Q to 0
for (int i = 0; i < maxCust; i++)
    info.Q[i] = 0;
```

The memory allocation is fine, but everything else is dubious indeed.  Your local variable `info` has zero elements in the `Q` member, so you can't initialize it reliably with the `for` loop.  It also isn't clear what you plan to do with `info`; why aren't you initializing `Q` (the pointer — a badly chosen name, if I may say so).  You should be using:

```
struct shiftInfo *shift = malloc(sizeof(struct shiftInfo) + (maxCust*sizeof(int)));
shift->simTime = atoi(argv[1]);
shift->arrivalRate = atof(argv[2]);
shift->tellers = atoi(argv[3]);
shift->serviceTime = atoi(argv[4]);
shift->sampleInterval = atoi(argv[5]);
for (int i = 0; i < maxCust; i++)
    shift->Q[i] = 0;
```

Now you can use `shift` (or whatever you choose to call it), setting a global pointer.  Note that you cannot usefully have structures with flexible array members as global variables (global pointers to them — yes; global variables — no), nor can you have them as automatic variables.  The trouble is that you cannot allocate any space for the flexible array member like that.

You will need to consider how you are going to control access to the global structure with multiple threads, and whether the serialized access to the global structure is going to become a serious bottleneck.  You will likely need a mutex and maybe some conditions.

As to your `timer` code: you need to convert the `void *` that is passed into the `struct ShiftInfo *`.

```
void *timer(void *vp)
{
    struct ShiftInfo *info = vp;
    int timeRemaining = info->simTime;
    while(timeRemaining){
        sleep(1);
        timeRemaining--;
        }
    return 0;
}
```

Note that you do need to return a value from the function.  Also, you need to consider whether this is going to do what you want.  It has a local variable that is changed.  You probably want to set the value in `info` to the time remaining.  And that needs mutex access around every operation.  I'm going to assume you add and initialize an extra member:

```
pthread_t mutex;
```

to your `struct shifInfo`.

```
void *timer(void *vp)
{
    struct shiftInfo *info = vp;
    if (pthread_mutex_lock(&info->mutex) != 0)
        return 0;  // Report error before returning?
    int *timeRemaining = &info->simTime;
    while (*timeRemaining > 0)
    {
        if (pthread_mutex_unlock(&info->mutex) != 0)
            return 0;  // Report error before returning?
        sleep(1);
        if (pthread_mutex_lock(&info->mutex) != 0)
            return 0;  // Report error before returning?
        (*timeRemaining)--;
    }
    if (pthread_mutex_unlock(&info->mutex) != 0)
        return 0;  // Report error before returning?
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your response, I made the suggested change, as seen now on this post, but am still receiving similar errors and warnings.  Also I am not too worried about access to the struct because the only aspect that changes is the timer and customer Q, although I don't know how to ensure two tellers don't try to get the same customer.

Comment: You ensure two tellers don't try to get the same customer by ensuring mutual exclusion while the threads access the data structure.  You can devise schemes with more than one mutex to control access to different parts of the structure, but the minimum requirement is one mutex.  You have to be very careful with multi-threaded applications accessing a global variable.

Comment: Thank you, I'll add that once I get the core code up and running, I don't think at this time that is causing issues because it would be more of an incorrect results error than a compiler issue.

Answer (score 0):

In timer() function, you have to cast info argument from (void *) to (struct shiftInfo *)

```
int timeRemaining = ((struct shiftInfo *)info) -> simTime;
```

Also, when creating customer, it should be like this

```
status = pthread_create(&customer, NULL, customer, (void *)&info);
```

Comment: Your suggestion for timeRemaining caused the error "error: âinfoâ undeclared (first use in this function)
  int timeRemaining = ((struct shiftInfo *)info) -> simTime;
" and wouldn't that make timeRemaining a local variable? I want it accessible from all threads.

Comment: Also, why can't customer be declared as "void *customer(void *info)" like the timer function?

Comment: Sorry, I was clearly very tired when I read your response, thanks for the advice @Phuc Nguyen V.